# Does an eighteen-year-old Oregon resident who obtained a driver license as a minor need to get a new license to tow a trailer?

Tags: united-states, driving, minor, oregon

In Oregon, drivers under eighteen years of age may not tow trailers. The "Provisional Driver License" issued to drivers aged sixteen through eighteen says it is valid for "[a]ny signle vehicle with a [GVWR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_weight#Gross_vehicle_weight_rating) of not more than 26,000 [pounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_(mass)) with the proper endorsements. Any emergency vehicle operated by a firefighter." This license remains valid after the driver turns eighteen; there is no need to replace it to continue driving single vehicles. If the driver wants to start towing trailers (and is not a firefighter), is it necessary to get a new license without the "single vehicle" restriction, or is it implied that this restriction only applies through age eighteen?

[image: A redacted image of the back of an Oregon provisional driver license issued to a sixteen-year-old driver, saying that it is valid for "[a]ny signle vehicle with a GVWR of not more than 26,000 pounds with the proper endorsements. Any emergency vehicle operated by a firefighter."]

Comment: Please provide evidence where you found that limitation, I don't see any trailer limitation on OR graduated licenses. Single vehicle <26,001 lbs GVWR is the standard class C license all over the country because Federal CDL requirements kick in at 26,001. Wherever you copied that from probably had further words explaining the [10k/26k trailer limit](https://www.oregon.gov/odot/dmv/pages/driverid/classes.aspx) for a class C.

Comment: @user71659 those words are copied from the back of my driver license.

Comment: So they ran out of space for the trailer words.

Comment: @user71659 I posted a redacted image of my license. My permit did not have the "single vehicle" restriction, but I don't remember the exact wording it had.

Comment: I found a sample image (https://duckduckgo.com/?q=oregon+driver+license+back&t=fpas&iax=images&ia=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pngitem.com%2Fpimgs%2Fm%2F277-2779603_oregon-drivers-license-back-hd-png-download.png) showing an adult's license, and it has the same wording mine does. It looks like that is what's on every license.

Comment: Exactly, they were too lazy/ran out of space to write all the conditions down. I don't see any evidence that Oregon limits towing for minors. [Some other states do](https://www.ncleg.net/enactedlegislation/statutes/html/bysection/chapter_20/gs_20-7.html). You have to find the exact statute to see when it no longer applies.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find the same wording on the Oregon DMV / law websites, but in a [Background Brief](https://www.oregonlegislature.gov/lpro/Publications/DriverLicenses.pdf) on the Oregon Legislature website, there is this statement, just after discussion of restrictions on a Class C provisional license:

> Upon reaching 18 years of age, individuals may qualify for a standard
> Class C license. This license allows the bearer to operate vehicles
> under 26,000 pounds, recreational vehicles, fire and emergency
> vehicles, **and to tow other vehicles and trailers with certain weight**
> **restrictions**.

Emphasis mine. The document is from 2012.